# Classify into group by date

Tags: r, operators

working on a survival analysis.  Have a data frame worksheet with a list of dates (as date class).  (worksheet$date.of.first.positive).  I would like to create another column where if the date falls within a range I label this column as group 0,1,2.
I've tried the following code:

```
if (worksheet$date.of.first.positive < '2011-07-01'){
  worksheet$aspera2 <- 0
}else if (worksheet$date.of.first.positive > '2012-10-01') {
  worksheet$aspera2 <- 2
} else{
  worksheet$aspera2 <- 1
}
```

I get the following error: 
Warning message:
In if (worksheet$date.of.first.positive < "2011-07-01") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I've read the logical vector answers but don't fully understand what I'm doing wrong.

Dinesh's response was exactly what I needed. I used the following. To nest the ifelse! Thanks!

```
worksheet$aspera2 <- ifelse(worksheet$date.of.first.positive < '2011-07-01', 0, ifelse(worksheet$date.of.first.positive > '2012-10-01', 2, 1))
```

Comment: You should learn to use R `Date`-class. Use `cut` or `findInterval`.

Comment: Or if you want to paly around with some Boolean gymnastics: `worksheet$aspera2 <- worksheet$date.of.first.positive >= '2011-07-01' + worksheet$date.of.first.positive > '2012-10-01'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message is terse but highly meaningful. the `IF` is returning a vector of T/F but the `if` doesn't work that way for you. Try an `ifelse` style

```
worksheet$aspera2 <- ifelse(worksheet$date.of.first.positive < '2011-07-01', "value-when-true", "value-when-false")
```

And you can nest `ifelse`

Comment: worked like a charm!! worksheet$aspera2 <- ifelse(worksheet$date.of.first.positive < '2011-07-01', 0, ifelse(worksheet$date.of.first.positive > '2012-10-01', 2, 0))